# How to re-order $_FILES (multiple upload) Array?

Tags: php

I'm improving some upload page, it got to upload more than one file per request send. But the way i receive the $_FILE array is complex and i can't use it as i want.

Basically, for each File uploaded i got to save one Row at Database, and to do it, i found out that treat every separated information as an array index would be better. Here is how i get the debug:

```
Array
(
    [UploadDocumentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [documentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => AntigoTratamentoDados.png
                            [1] => tratamentoDados.png
                            [2] => tratamentoDadosMeuConsignado.png
                        )
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [documentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image/png
                            [1] => image/png
                            [2] => image/png
                        )
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [documentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /tmp/phpHzKqiE
                            [1] => /tmp/phpnjGTRF
                            [2] => /tmp/php73hnrH
                        )
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [documentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 0
                        )
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [documentoCentralAtendimento] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 77067
                            [1] => 25496
                            [2] => 20898
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And how i want to receive:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => AntigoTratamentoDados.png
            [tempName] => /tmp/phpP8lIN6
            [type] => image/png
            [size] => 77067
            [error] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => tratamentoDados.png
            [tempName] => /tmp/phptzwJX8
            [type] => image/png
            [size] => 25496
            [error] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => tratamentoDadosMeuConsignado.png
            [tempName] => /tmp/phpTySL7a
            [type] => image/png
            [size] => 20898
            [error] => 0
        )
)
```

And here is my HTML input:

```
<input id="uploaddocumentocentralatendimento-documentocentralatendimento" class="form-field" name="UploadDocumentoCentralAtendimento[documentoCentralAtendimento][]" multiple="" type="file">
```

I've tried some recursive strategy but none worked to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over one of subarrays and collect values from other subarrays under same key `$k`:

```
$newFiles = [];
foreach ($_FILES['UploadDocumentoCentralAtendimento']['name']['documentoCentralAtendimento'] as $k => $v) {
    $newFiles[] = [
        'name' => $v,
        'type' => $_FILES['UploadDocumentoCentralAtendimento']['type']['documentoCentralAtendimento'][$k],
        // etc
    ];
}
```

Comment: It did work, it was so simple that i'm sad i couldn't recognize haha. Thank you so much!